# Different timestamp on php_error.log

Tags: php, macos, debugging, syslog

I'm using MAMP on a MacBook Pro, and whenever I took a look into the php_error.log I get each error with a timestap from Berlin but I'm in South America.

```
[16-Jan-2016 03:06:40 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:
```

The actual time when that error happened was 21:06.

how can I change this timestamp? I know is not a big deal but is easier to debug when the date is correct.

Comment: Are you setting it to Berlin with `date_default_timezone_set` anywhere in your code?

Comment: no, in fact I've never tried to set a different timezone nor by `date_default_timezone_set` or by system preferences [the actual timezone is: Colombia Standard Time].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timezone is indeed set to Berlin somewhere in your system or code.

1. Check /usr/local/etc/php/(version)/php.ini file and look for date.timezone setting. A full list of supported timezones is available [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). Modify this setting if necessary and restart your PHP process/server. Even if the setting was not present, it's a good idea to fix that now!
2. Check if 'Europe/Berlin' is set somewhere in your code. Simple way to look in all PHP files in the folder:

> find . -name "*.php" -exec grep -H "Europe/Berlin" {} \;

Comment: Since I'm using MAMP which allows me to use different PHP versions I had to look on /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0/conf/php.ini instead of /usr/local... and there I changed the date.timezone value and voilá! thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's to change the **timezone**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); //example
?>
```

Here's the link [PHP Set Timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Thanks! do I need to change the timezone each time I create a php file or will this set it by default to L.A. Timezone?